# Displaying welcome screen only once

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native application and I want to display a welcome screen when the application is first installed.

I have a welcome screen, and when the user clicks on the continue button, I have an async storage value that changes so I know if I should display the screen or not.

In app.js, I check for that value to determine if I should display Home or Welcome.

This is what I have in app.tsx:

```
      const [shouldDisplayWelcome, setShouldDisplayWelcome] = useState<boolean>(true);
      useEffect(() => {
        StorageManager.getInstance().getData(Key.firstTime).then((firstTime) => {
          if (firstTime != undefined) {
            setShouldDisplayWelcome(firstTime);
          }
        })    
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <ThemeProvider>
          <Provider store={store}>
            {
                <NavigationContainer>
                  <Stack.Navigator>
                    {
                      shouldDisplayWelcome && <Stack.Screen
                        name="Welcome"
                        component={Welcome}
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                      />
                    }
                    <Stack.Screen
                      name="Home"
                      component={Home}
                      options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                      name="Settings"
                      component={Settings}
                      options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    />
                  </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            }
          </Provider>
        </ThemeProvider>
```

It is working, but when the user closes the app and then comes back to it, there is a flicker that shows the Welcome screen and goes right to the Home screen.
I guess that's because getting the data is async operation, but I couldn't figure out how to solve this, so if there is no need to display the Welcome screen, it won't show it for half a second before getting the answer from `StorageManager`.

Edit:
I tried to 'hold' the application until the async function finishes, like this:

```
 const chooseScreen = async () => {
    await StorageManager.getInstance().getData(Key.firstTime).then((result) => {
      if (result != undefined) {
        setShouldDisplayWelcome(result);
      }
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    chooseScreen();
  }, [])
```

But this also didn't work.

Comment: Why not add a loading screen to render till the async await can be established from Storage Manager then once the condition is checked proceed with one screen or the other.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Thanks, but I'm assuming there is a way to get it work as needed and adding a loading screen is not something I can consider right now.

Comment: The loading screen is typically the recommended way though.

Answer (score 1):

I got a workaround to fix this issue, not sure if that's the best solution, but it does work.
What I did was to create another state named `loading` and set it to true.
Then, after the async function finishes, I set `loading` to false in the `finally` block.
I set `App.tsx` to render my `NavigationContainer` only when `loading` is false which only happens after the async operation finished.
The issue where the welcome screen was flickering at the start not happening anymore.

```
const App = () => {
  const [shouldDisplayWelcome, setShouldDisplayWelcome] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const chooseScreen = async () => {
    await StorageManager.getInstance().getData(Key.firstTime).then((result) => {
      if (result != undefined) setShouldDisplayWelcome(result);
    }).finally(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    chooseScreen();
  }, [])

  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        {
          !loading &&
          <NavigationContainer>
            ....
          </NavigationContainer>
        }
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom hook to get the asynchronous value. While waiting/loading, you should return "null" or something else intelligent.

`onboardingIsLoading` gives you the loading state

```js
import useGetOnboardingStatus from "../../utils/useGetOnboardingStatus";

const { isFirstLaunch, isLoading: onboardingIsLoading } =
    useGetOnboardingStatus();
```

Hook:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

async function checkIfFirstLaunch() {
  try {
    const hasFirstLaunched = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user_onboarded");
    if (hasFirstLaunched === null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

const useGetOnboardingStatus = () => {
  const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = useState(false);
  const [isFirstLaunchIsLoading, setIsFirstLaunchIsLoading] = useState(true);

  React.useEffect(async () => {
    const firstLaunch = await checkIfFirstLaunch();
    setIsFirstLaunch(firstLaunch);
    setIsFirstLaunchIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return {
    isFirstLaunch: isFirstLaunch,
    isLoading: isFirstLaunchIsLoading,
  };
};

export default useGetOnboardingStatus;
```